# Link button with arrow sides using css

Tags: css, button

I'm wondering if there is a css only solution to display a link button like the one below. Any advises?

[image]

Comment: it is possible check this [examples](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use pseudo elements and some border property then adjust the different values to get what you want:

```css
.link {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.link:before,.link:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  left: -19px;
  top: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
.link:after {
  right: -19px;
  left:auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code! You pointed me to the right direction! After applying some scaling on the pseudo elements I managed to make it look exactly like the image.